# Convertir un String a DateTime

Tags: string, flutter, datetime

Recibo un dato llamado `RecordDate` en tipo *String* a través de un JSON:

```
class Record {
    Record({
        required this.RecordDate,
        required this.EntryTime,
        required this.ExitTime,
    });

    String RecordDate;
    String EntryTime;
    String ExitTime;

    factory Record.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) => Record(
        RecordDate: json["RecordDate"],
        EntryTime: json["EntryTime"],
        ExitTime: json["ExitTime"],
    );

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "RecordDate": RecordDate,
        "EntryTime": EntryTime,
        "ExitTime": ExitTime,
    };
}
```

Y cargo los datos en un `ListTile.builder`:

```
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          snapshot.data![index].RecordDate,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Pero el texto se muestra de la siguiente manera:

**"2022-04-08T05:00:00.000Z"**

Cómo podría adaptar el dato a "Abril 08, 2022"?

Comment: Seguro que el final te llega  así : "2022-04-08T05:00:00:000Z" y no asi: "2022-04-08T05:00:00.000Z"?

Comment: Disculpa, ya lo corregí. Si es "2022-04-08T05:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las formas sería esta:

```
 String fecha= snapshot.data![index].RecordDate;

            final parsearFecha = DateTime.parse(fecha);

            final formatoFecha =
                DateFormat('MMMM dd, yyyy').format(parsearFecha);

            print(formatoFecha);

            //resultado: April 08, 2022
```

Otra forma sería esta de aca, donde esta función la asignas directamente en la propiedad `Text` y solo le pasas como parámetro `snapshot.data![index].RecordDate` y así por cada registro te convertiría la fecha, aquí el ejemplo:

```
    String convertirFecha(String fecha) {
    String date = fecha;
    String? mes;
    String? fechaFinal;
    final parsearFecha = DateTime.parse(date);
    //final formatoFecha = DateFormat('MMMM dd, yyyy').format(parsearFecha);
    switch (parsearFecha.month) {
      case 01:
        mes = 'Enero';
        break;
      case 02:
        mes = 'Febrero';
        break;
      case 03:
        mes = 'Marzo';
        break;
      case 04:
        mes = 'Abril';
        break;
      case 05:
        mes = 'Mayo';
        break;
      case 06:
        mes = 'Junio';
        break;
      case 07:
        mes = 'Julio';
        break;
      case 08:
        mes = 'Agosto';
        break;
      case 09:
        mes = 'Septiembre';
        break;
      case 10:
        mes = 'Octubre';
        break;
      case 11:
        mes = 'Noviembre';
        break;
      case 12:
        mes = 'Diciembre';
        break;
      default:
    }
    setState(() {
      fechaFinal = "$mes ${parsearFecha.day}, ${parsearFecha.year}";
    });
    debugPrint(fechaFinal!);
    //resultado: Abril 8, 2022
    return fechaFinal!;
  }
```

Normalmente yo uso la segunda forma, me entiendo mejor de esa forma, no te olvides de usar el paquete [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

Comment: Utilicé la segunda forma, y funcionó quitándole el setState(), muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr ese efecto usando el paquete [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('MMMM-dd-yyyy');//modificas aqui el formato
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted);
}
```